# Dropbox is not syncing files

Tags: dropbox

I have two macs with a Dropbox folder syncing between them.

The Dropbox on my iMac is not syncing properly, i.e. when I add new files, it just does not sync them. Only when I pause and then sync again does it get synced. How can I solve this?

(I have Monterey 12.4)

Comment: You might try signing out of Dropbox on both devices, then sign in again. Other potential issues - selective sync is enabled, or you are out of storage space on your Dropbox plan…

Comment: @dr.nixon thanks! I am not out of storage. and I tried signing out and in. this does not solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have another device you can try? Windows box, iOS device, etc. to help determine if the issue is only with one of your computers?

Comment: I have another mac that does not exhibit this problem. I tried to uninstall and install the dropbox program from the problematic mac, but it did not help.